# Relation between Bott-Chern forms and Second fundamental form

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, complex-geometry, vector-bundles, characteristic-classes

Given a short exact sequence of holomorphic Hermitian vector bundles
$$0\rightarrow F\rightarrow E\rightarrow G\rightarrow 0,$$
the second fundamental form measures the obstruction of $E\simeq F\oplus G$ to be holomorphic. On the other hand the Bott-Chern forms also vanish when the sequence splits orthogonally and holomorphically.

Is there any known relation between these two invariants?

Comment: I think Proposition 3 at pg 29 here http://www.math.stonybrook.edu/~leontak/On%20Bott-Chern%20forms%20and%20their%20applications.pdf partially answers the question